# Android Developer console

Tags: google-play

i have uploaded an android app today and a few of my family and friends have downloaded it today, but when i go to my developer page the download and active download is still 0. is there some code that i have to add in order to get the stupid counter to start? or does it take few days?

Is there something that i need to code in my android manifest?? If so, can i get some sample code..or a link would be very helpful.

```
<manifest . . . >
<application . . . >
    <service android:name="com.example.project.SecretService" . . . >
        . . .
    </service>
    . . .
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple app about two weeks ago, I did not have to add anything special into my manifest or code at all.  I would give it a full day to generate the stats. It might only apply the count at midnight or such to give a total for that given day.